# GPRS/SMS for node-red

Tags: raspberry-pi3, node-red

What is the best option to **push** or send **SMS** on phone?!

I see `pushbullet`, but for this you need internet on.
I also see `Twilio` for sms(payable)

Or is there any dev for `FONA(gprs module)`?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org/). It runs on Linux lets you send SMS messages via HTTP calls.

I have an [instance](https://www.hardill.me.uk/wordpress/2010/02/26/how-to-get-personal-cctv-mmsd-to-your-phone/) running with a USB 3G dongle combined with it's partner app mbuni (that allows MMS messages to be sent) on a Pi being driven by node-red.

Answer (score 0):

Another service that supports sending SMS in Node-RED is [@sinch/node-red-conversation-api](https://flows.nodered.org/node/@sinch/node-red-conversation-api). If you'd like to send messages for free and don't mind using other messaging channels, it supports quite the number of additional channels as well, like WhatsApp, Telegram and Messenger.